# Adding two different types of slider in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I initially have one type of slider already present in my code to switch on/off my device, I wish to add another range slider to vary duration of ON time but when I do so all my slider turn to range slider, is there some other way to do so, since I'm using both HTML and JavaScript to fetch the user input and let the device act accordingly.

This is my slider code:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: green;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px green;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(66px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(66px);
  transform: translateX(66px);
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 200;
}


/*
    
this is another slider which i wish to add:

*/

.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<tr height=40>
  <td>
    <style="text-align:middle">PORT1</td>
  <td width=40></td>
  <td><label id="sw1" , class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span class="slider"></span> 
   </label></td>
  <td>
    <div class="slidercontainer">
      <input type="range" min="10" max="120" value="20" class="slider" id="pulse_time">
      <p>Time:<span id="P1_PT"></span></p>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you provide us what you've done so we can search where the problem can come from please

Comment: yes,I have added some snippets of my code please have a look.

Comment: Add your JavaScript that you tried if that is what you want fixed. " here i want to call it" - and how exactly would you or what have you tried?  Notice the syntax issue(s) you have also.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to show slider if first is checked, you'll need to review css

```js
function changeVisibility(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.getElementById("onlyShowIfYes").style.visibility = "visible"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("onlyShowIfYes").style.visibility = "hidden"
  }
}

document.getElementById("check").onchange = changeVisibility
changeVisibility({target: {checked: false}})
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: green;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px green;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(66px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(66px);
  transform: translateX(66px);
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 200;
}


/*
    
this is another slider which i wish to add:

*/

.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<tr height=40>
  <td>
    <style="text-align:middle">PORT1</td>
  <td width=40></td>
  <td><label id="sw1" , class="switch">
   <input id="check" type="checkbox">
   <span class="slider"></span> 
   </label></td>
  <td>
    <div id="onlyShowIfYes" class="slidercontainer">
      <input type="range" min="10" max="120" value="20" class="slider" id="pulse_time">
      <p>Time:<span id="P1_PT"></span></p>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: hello,I executed this code snippet but my issue remained the same, both the slider turned similar (instead both have different format as allotted) and i needed slider before "checking" the port.

Comment: @Mandeep.m there is only one slider in the HTML you provided

Comment: I have another form of slider to switch on/off the port,i have moved forward in this code and decided to use default range slider.but my slider now tends to submit all the inputs before pressing the submit button(probably submit button is not working) i wish to submit after setting up the range